# Obtain list of class methods for an arbitrary class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

How can I get the list of *class* methods for a particular Class?  I've tried using the `class_copyMethodList` function declared in `<objc/runtime.h>`, but that's only giving me instance methods.  I've also found a function that gives me a Method for a class method, but only if I have the selector to the method first (`class_getClassMethod`).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`class_copyMethodList` returns the instance methods of the passed class. The class methods are actually instance methods of the class's metaclass.

The solution to your problem is included right in the [API Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyMethodList) for `class_copyMethodList`.

Answer (score 26):

Use the metaclass.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

int unsigned numMethods;
Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(objc_getMetaClass("NSArray"), &numMethods);
for (int i = 0; i < numMethods; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methods[i])));
}
free(methods);
```

Comment: As that's a `copy` method, don't forget to `free(methods)` when you're done with it. Regardless of whether you're using ARC — C allocations are not reference counted so automatic reference counting isn't going to help you with that.

Comment: The documentation seems a bit fuzzy on the import path, I used: #import <objc/runtime.h>